# cmake link error on linking shared library hierarchy to executable

Tags: cmake

In my project I have the following configuration:

- *low level shared library*
- *shared library* that is a wrapper of low level shared library
- *executable*

**so the files tree is** :

```
CMakeLists.txt
SharedLibraryBase
    CMakeLists.txt
    inc
       myLibBase.h    -> defines MyLibBaseFunction()
    src
       myLibBase.cpp -> implements MyLibBaseFunction()
MySharedLibrary
    CMakeLists.txt
    inc
       myLib.h       -> defines MyLibFunction()
    src
       myLib.cpp     -> implements MyLibFunction()
Executables
    CMakeLists.txt
    inc
       main.h 
    src
       main.cpp   -> calls MyLibFunction()
```

**When I perform make , I get a following link error:**

> ld.exe: cannot find -lMySharedLibrary

the **main CMakeLists.txt** is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestSharedLibraryProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "my_outputs")
message("Binary tree path : ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
add_subdirectory(SharedLibraryBase)
add_subdirectory(MySharedLibrary)
add_subdirectory(Executables)
```

the **low level shared library CMakeLists.txt** is:

```
###########################
#   SharedLibraiesBase    #
###########################
project(SharedLibraryBase)

# include directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)

# find source files
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_headers inc/myLibBase.h)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources src/myLib.cpp)

# create shared library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_headers} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})

# add files to export to 'include'
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY PUBLIC_HEADER inc/myLibBase.h)

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

the **wrapper shared library CMakeLists.txt** is:

```
#######################
#   SharedLibraies    #
#######################
project(MySharedLibrary)

# include directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} inc ../SharedLibraryBase/inc)

# find source files
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_headers inc/myLib.h)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources src/myLib.cpp)

# create shared library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_headers} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})

#dependency shared library (from this project)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SharedLibraryBase)

# add files to export to 'include'
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY PUBLIC_HEADER inc/myLib.h)

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

the **executable CMakeLists.txt** is:

```
####################
#   Executables    #
####################
project(Executables)

# include directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}/inc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../MySharedLibrary/inc)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_headers inc/main.h)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources src/main.cpp)

#create executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_headers} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})

#dependency shared library (from this project)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} MyShraedLibrary)

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ordinary type error MyShraedLibrary instead of MySharedLibrary